# How can this autoloader be improved?

Tags: php, object-oriented

I don't understand the concept of autoloaders, other than the bare minimum, which is that to load a class file when the class is being called. Or as the PHP manual cites it, to avoid having to `require` multiple time.

I get that, but what I don't understand is the complexity behind almost all the autoloaders which I sought to learn some things from. It's almost impossible to understand what goes on behind the scenes.

Just to understand it a bit more with your help, I made a simple autoloader as you can see below:

```
class Autoloader
{
    private $pathToClass; 

    //register the path
    function __construct($pathToClass)
    {
        $this->pathToClass = $pathToClass; 
    }

    //load the file
    public function load($class)
    {

        // expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)
        $explode = explode('\\', $class); 

        //get the last exploaded string and append .php so it becomes tar.php
        $class = $explode[count($explode) - 1].'.php'; 

        // required tar.php in the path it is found ex:
        // require '/foo/bar/tar.php' in lowecase to avoid windows/unix conflict
        if(file_exists(strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class))){
             require strtolower($this->pathToClass.$class);

            return true; 
        }

        return false; 
    }   

    // autoload
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}
```

The class explains itself. It does work, and I just would like to know what I am missing?  As you can see, it is the most basic autoloader.  What would be the next most important thing you would add to it?

Here is how it is instantiated:

```
$myLibLoader = new Autoloader(__DIR__.'/foo/bar/');
$myLibLoader->register();


$foo =  new foo();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comments on your code**

- The access modifier for your constructor is missing.

  ```
  function __construct...
  public function __construct
  ```

  Although no specified access modifier on methods means that PHP chooses *public* automatically (see [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)), I would add it for consistency.
- Your autoloader does not cope with namespaces. You might want to read [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md), a specification stating how autoloaders should cope with namespaces, folders and filenames.
- Do not add random newlines.

  ```
  public function load($class)
  {

      // expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)

  public function load($class)
  {
      // expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)
  ```
- Do not add random spaces in comments.

  ```
  // expload the namespaces ex: foo\bar\tar array(foo, bar, tar)
  //get the last exploaded string and append .php so it becomes tar.php
  ```

  Be consistent! I suggest using a space after `//`.
- Be specific in variable names. `$pathToClass` lets me think that the string points to a specific class file. It does however point to a directory containing class files. I suggest using `$classDir`. `$class` is also an edge case since it does contain more than a single class name.
- You don't need `explode` if you only wish to extract the class name.
  Use [strrpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

  ```
  $classFilename = substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1) . '.php';
  ```
- Don't apply `strtolower` two times. Just save the result in a temporary variable. It makes your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).
- Since you declare `pathToClass` private anyway, consider marking the class `final`. Some arguments are provided in an article [Final should be Default for Classes in Java](http://whiley.org/2011/12/06/final-should-be-default-for-classes-in-java/) (the same principles not only apply to Java, but also to many other languages including PHP).
- Mark your `load` method private. It's an implementation detail, which shouldn't be accessible from outside the class.
- Your `load` method is not required to return a boolean value. Returning true or false is not bad per se, maybe you will want to encapsulate the autoloading mechanism further and throw exceptions depending on the return value.

---

**Elaborating on the PSR-0 specification**

The [spec](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/cf763049740aaa2a4febd217da9786b22eb61921/accepted/PSR-0.md) defines mandatory requirements your autoloader must fulfill.

They provide example inputs your autoloader must accept:

```
\Doctrine\Common\IsolatedClassLoader => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/Doctrine/Common/IsolatedClassLoader.php
\Symfony\Core\Request => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/Symfony/Core/Request.php
\Zend\Acl => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/Zend/Acl.php
\Zend\Mail\Message => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/Zend/Mail/Message.php

\namespace\package\Class_Name => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package/Class/Name.php
\namespace\package_name\Class_Name => /path/to/project/lib/vendor/namespace/package_name/Class/Name.php
```

Roughly speaking, your code is missing the following aspects:

- Taking the namespace into account and using it to build a directory hierarchy.
- Transforming underscores in class names to a directory hierarchy as well.

Comment: First thanks for the answer, but when I asked the question about improving, I was not referring to naming inconsistencies, comments or about access modifiers. I was more asking about what is the *next* step to make this autoloader more trivial than it *is*. You did bring an interesting note about the PSR though. I don't understand much about the PSR (If I did, I wouldn't be using this autoloader) so, it would be nice if you could explain what this class is missing from the PSR

Comment: *less trivial than it is :)

Comment: @CONtext Well, it's always good to improve one's code as well :) I did elaborate a bit on PSR-0, please see my update.

Comment: Ok, I got the second point. Seems pretty straight forward. I should use `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` to make my autoloader namespace friendly. As some frameworks use underscore `_`  and others use `\` But the first point is tough to understand. Does it mean if I am loading a class as `$foo = new foo\bar\tar\register` then, that class `register` or `register.php` should be stored inside `foo\bar\tar\` folder? should the full namespace be identical to the folder structure?

Comment: @CONtext Exactly, the qualifier `foo\bar\tar\register` requires you (according to PSR-0) to load `register.php` from the path `foo/bar/tar`. Note that underscores only play a role in class names. They remain in package names as is.

Comment: Ok, I am accepting this answer, because it was very good. And I just spent 1 hour building [another autoloader](http://pastebin.com/7PV7yWjt) and the result was goodish.. but there is something wrong with it. It can autoload a single class at a time. If I declare two, (as seen in the example) it won't work. And as opposed to the [code shown here](https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634#file-splclassloader-php-L29) I fail to understand why passing the namespace is important at all.

Comment: You still don't construct a path from the class qualifier passed to load(). As the question how to do this is offtopic on CodeReview, consider posting on StackOverflow (with a clear explanation on the parts you don't understand).